# Person communicates with alien through a small piece of matter

Tags: story-identification, aliens, black-hole

I really don't remember all the details of this book, but a scientist makes a crystal of some sort and finds out he can use it to communicate with an alien, eventually, the alien gets the scientist to create a small black hole that is eating the earth.
The book was in English and I must have read it around 2003-2003.

Comment: Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you read it?  What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: People who vote to close story-ID questions because there are "too many possible answers" should be required to name two or three of them.

Comment: Although I doubt it's the one you're looking for, it has some similarities with The Gods Themselves, by Isaac Asimov

Comment: No it wasn't Asimov or anyone popular. I bought it at a booksale on a whim. I think the crystal was an isotope of beryllium or something.

Comment: That _really_ sounds like _The Gods Themselves_, actually.